# Slider plugin not loading/showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider

I've installed the plugin Layerslider in WordPress and it's just not showing at all.
I've deleted all other plugins, tried installing through the control panel and via FTP and nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Link is: http://dev.themarketcreative.com/

Comment: Hmmm ... your javascript is loading, but I don't see any layerslider stylesheet in there.  Let me check one of my domains that utilizes the layerslider and I'll get back with you.  And you're sure you've put the proper shortcode in your homepage (or widget in your homepage)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've used the PHP code they generate and tried the shortcode route too. Thank you for your help thus far :)

Comment: I take that back ... I just viewed your source, and neither your stylesheets or your javascript files are loading.  There are 4 external javascripts in your /layerslider/js/ folder.  These should be in there.  Do you see something like this in your WordPress admin?  http://i.imgur.com/Y3agoLn.jpg

Comment: There actually isn'ta /js folder in there. It's the same with a previous site I used but that one works. Maybe this is the issue? I tried re-downloading and it still doesn't have the js folder in there.

Answer (score 1):

i have checked you site and there is Jquery error is showing that's why slider is not working

1).ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
2).TypeError: lsjQuery is not a function

To remove this error there is one option in layer slider "Put JS includes to body"

to select that option go
Layer-slider->edit->global settings   Tab call "Troubleshooting" select 'Put JS includes to body' and checked

hope this will help

Comment: @user3181828 you are using javascript under<div class="home-slider"></div> and all js included after it please includes all js file in header or before home slider div and check..

Comment: user3181828 Now all error has been removed.. Now the problem with your images path please update is also..

Comment: Is the preview working properly in your Layerslider WordPress admin area?

Comment: Simple shortcode like [layerslider id="1"] is all you need.  It should be on your homepage or in a text widget in a widget area on your homepage.

Comment: Preview is working fine. Now it's started showing the arrows too but the functionality still isn't working. The height is messed up and the images dissapear when we click on the next arrow?

Comment: Well, now everything is all set on our end.  Now it's time for you to dig into the settings of your Layerslider and figure out what you're doing wrong.  Don't forget to + Narendra's answer and accept his answer to give him credit. If you're sure your settings are correct, try deactivating all other plugins again and clear your website's cache if you're using a caching plugin and refresh your homepage.

Comment: Now every thing is fine, you just have to setup the slider through slider setting. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help thus far. How do I check if the Javascript is working fine? It's not a case of the slider settings as the second image always disappears and then won't go to the previous slide after that?

Comment: For example, I've added the sample slider on the page and it's not working whatsoever. Any ideaS?

Comment: Here, user, I'll set up a chat for you, and I'll invite Narendra too, since we shouldn't be commenting too much on one thread.

Comment: Actually you can't chat since you're not up to 20 reputation yet.  I'm really not supposed to give out e-mail and stuff like that here.  But I'm jasonpaulweber on yahoo messenger and the same on Facebook.